Stress pattern in "Little Red Riding Hood"
I was surprised to see that the primary stress in the phrase "Little Red Riding Hood" falls into the first syllable in "Riding". I expected the primary stress would fall into the word "Hood" since "Riding" is the action that is clearly NOT supported by the "Hood".
This pattern is quite popular for many English words for example "Running Water", "Talking Head", "Falling Star". There are exceptions as always but there're reasons behind those things historically or linguistically. However, I can't find any resources that explain why "Little Red Riding Hood" is stressed that way.
Could someone help to give me some hints?

Tradition? It's effectively a personal name, not an item of clothing. Also, it's "riding".

Does this answer your question? Can "Apple" be an adjective? 'Another way to tell a noun from an adjective in this position is by stress. Adjectives are not stressed, but nouns are. With 'racing horse', you can do it both ways: one as an unstressed adjective (a racing horse) if the horse is racing down the path, and the other as a stressed noun (a racing horse) is the horse that’s been bred for racing.' [tchrist]

@EdwinAshworth, I'm aware of what's in the question's answer. It's indeed mentioned in a book by Beverly Collins and Inger M. Mess.

@StuartF, so I guess you mean the girl's name is "ridding"?

But you accept an answer repeating this explanation?

No, 'Riding' isn't her real name, but (according to the story) she is known by the nickname 'Little Red Riding Hood' because she is a little girl who usually wears a red hood.

@EdwinAshworth, Of course, but I'd already accepted Rosie F's answer before seeing your comment above.

You have accepted a somewhat incorrect answer! It's probably best to wait a couple of days before accepting an answer. Many other people may have interesting (or more accurate) things to say. But they may not bother to write you an answer if you have already accepted one. It's perhaps worth looking at my comment to Tchrist and Rosie under the currently selected answer. [By the way, Inger's surname is Mees, not Mess!!! ;-) ]

Cf. Little Red Riding Hood and hear how naturally the stresses of the name fall on the full quarters.

compounds and phrases: compound nouns vs free combinations & collocations has the answer (Greg Lee):  'Telling the difference between a compound noun and a modified noun is not straightforward, but one way that often works is to consider the stress. A modified noun has primary stress at the end, while a compound noun has stress at the beginning. There are exceptions....'

@EdwinAshworth That post's very misleading and doesn't differentiate between  items that have one stress on the first element, one stress on the second, or stresses on both. It also doesn't differentiate between having a nucleus and having a 'primary stress'. The noun phrase "Old  people" doesn't have 'primary stress at the end' in "Old people are wise", for example. That answer is absolutely all over the place. And should not be recommended to readers here.

Hey -- try  "Ladle Raid Rotten Hut"   (part of a famous humor book)

In "running water" and your other examples, the first word is an adjective. By contrast, in "riding hood", "riding" is an adjunct specifying the kind of hood. Such adjuncts are usually stressed more than the nouns they modify. Examples: swimming cap, riding jacket.

This is the correct answer. Nouns get stressed, but adjectives do not: RUNNING shoes vs running WATER. The hood is for riding. It is not a hood that is riding.

@Rosie F Thanks for the answer, it's something I didn't know of. Are there any books, articles mentioning this specific case (I guess yes)?

Likewise, voting machine, sewing machine, answering machine, adding machine, washing machine, calling card (where the stress position is the same as in credit card, and for the same reason), ironing board, running shoes. Ok, ok, I‘love stop here.

@tchrist Not quite!  Attributive  adjectives are adjuncts. Those words, "running" etc, are also adjuncts, but they are verbs, not adjectives. The difference in stress is due to the fact that riding hood is a compound noun. Compound nouns (as a rough generalisation - there are lots of subrules) are stressed on the first word. Note that the water runs, the heads talk, the star falls, but that the hood does not ride!!! Note as well that a ['smoking 'jacket] is on fire whilst a ['smoking jacket] isn't!

@Araucaria Good point. "Bright falling star": "bright" modifies "star". "Brightly shining star": "brightly" modifies "shining" and is an adverb because "shining" is a verb.

Note that stress patterns vary between regions: there are many   cases where US English stresses the modifier by default, while UK English stresses the noun.  (For example, in apple sauce, US English stresses the modifier enough to justify combining it into a single word — which sounds very wrong to UK English ears!)  — However, this answer shows that that doesn't apply to all such cases.

@gidds I don’t perceive any US/UK difference in how apple sauce is stressed. Sauce is unstressed (or weakly stressed) in both, and stressing it as if it were modified by an adjective sounds distinctly unnatural in both. There are compounds, of course, where the stress pattern differs, such as waistcoat (AmE /ˈweɪst(ˌ)koʊt/ vs [now dated] BrE /ˈwεskɪt/), but I wouldn’t consider apple sauce one.

@Araucaria Was your comment in response to a comment that’s no longer there? I don’t see any mention of adjuncts in tchrist’s comment above…

@JanusBahsJacquet It's from Rosie's post"In "running water" and your other examples, the first word is an adjective. By contrast, in "riding hood", "riding" is an adjunct". Tchrist then said "This is the correct answer ..."  etc

@Araucaria-Him Oh, now I see it. Though to be fair this type of attributive noun is often called ‘noun adjuncts’, so it’s an understandable mistake. I didn’t even notice it just said ‘adjuncts’ when I read the answer, just automatically mentally read it as ‘noun adjuncts’.

The basic rule  for compound nouns is that the first element takes stress and the second doesn't (and it doesn't matter whether the compound noun is written as one word or two). Consider:

'stepping stone
'handbag
'aeroplane
'body builder
'writing paper
com'puter screen
'walking stick

Notice that the first word in the compound noun is itself usually a noun, but may be an adjective or occasionally a verb. It makes no difference.
The compound noun "riding hood" like the compound noun "smoking jacket" or the compound "swimming costume" is regular and only takes stress on the first element.
Here, the words "little" and "red" are both attributive adjectives functioning as adjuncts within the larger noun phrase. And, for this reason, both of these words are stressed. In a run of three stressed words, the middle one is always less prominent, and so the word "red" will not be as prominent as the words "little" or "riding".
The Original Poster compares the noun phrase "'Little 'Red 'Riding  Hood", which involves a compound noun, with the following noun phrases, which don't:

'running 'water
'falling 'star
'talking 'heads

The noun phrases above all involve a noun modified by an attributive present participle verb functioning as an adjunct. Notice that adjectives are always stative in meaning whereas verbs are often dynamic. In the noun phrases above the water runs, the star is falling the heads talk. Because verbs are content words and usually stressed and the same goes for nouns, the noun phrases above have stress on both elements.
Notice, then, that we have a clear contrast here with the Original Poster's "Little Red Riding Hood". In that noun phrase, the hood is not riding! And because "riding hood" is a compound noun it only has a single lexical stress, which is exactly what we should expect.
Ain't English fun!
That's all, folks!

I think you mean "That's all, folks!" But I suppose you could mean your entire answer was folksy in the extreme, in which case never mind. ^_^

@Robusto Roger!

Also +1 for your answer, so you know I'm not just a cheapskate critic.

An interesting albeit very contrived example: compare "The hunters went down to the pond to shoot the drinking game" vs. "The college students were playing a drinking game."

Greg Lee addressed this (without examples) back in 2015. He did mention that there were exceptions. // CGEL apparently don't accept the open compound analysis.

@alphabet Yep. Great contrast.

@EdwinAshworth Got a link at all?

My second comment accompanying OP. Or if you mean to 'CGEL apparently don't accept the open compound analysis', this has been in comments where BillJ has discounted 'ink well' say as a single lexeme.

@EdwinAshworth I meant to Greg Lee.

Yes, your answer looks better. But Greg Lee is a recognised linguist; the answer here lacks authoritative references.

So adding references should be a doddle.

@EdwinAshworth Unlikely,, as he hasn’t been seen for several years now.

Surely the famous phoneticians published (or referenced) articles on the topic? These would be peer-reviewed. The greatly missed JL used to reference his own papers where relevant.

@EdwinAshworth You won't normally find people writing papers breaking the news that verbs sometimes take objects or that English nouns can be plurals. Or that nouns tend to have first syllable stress. Or that content words have stress.

You find papers showing analyses / exceptions /further thoughts that include the basics. But if it's so basic, vote to transfer to ELL.

Running water is water that runs; talking heads are heads that talk; a falling star is a star that falls. But a riding hood is not a hood that rides; it is a hood for riding.
Suppose you are a runner, and you take water on your runs to keep you hydrated. Somebody asks you for a sip; you might say "No, that's my running water!" with the stress on running.

+1 Nice example.

+! This does provide me another perspective!

The fact is that "riding" is the initial spelling that is found in "riding hood".

(The Free Dictionary) riding hood
A hood formerly worn by women when riding
A kind of cloak with a hood.

"little red ridding hood" is extremely rare, and most probably a spelling error.

From A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language this compound should be stressed on "riding".

(CoGEL § I.63)
[A] 'SWIMMING ˌPOOL : verbal noun in -ing + adverbial (consisting of a
prepositional phrase; cf  'X swims in the pool'). This is a very productive
type. Several adverbial relations are involved […]. For example:
PLACE
                    diving board ['dive from a board']
                    drinking cup ['drink from a cup']
[…]
INSTRUMENTAL
                    ad'ding machine
['add with a machine']
                    baking powder
['bake with powder']
                    walking stick ['walk with a stick']
                    riding hood
['ride with a hood']
[…]


The question isn't about spelling at all; OP made a spelling mistake incidental to the question.

@KarlKnechtel It's not about spelling, but in case the spelling "little red ridding hood" has been found by the original poster, there is the assurance that this is not the usual spelling.

"Little red ridding hood" is not only rare, it's non-existent. It says so in the ngram plot itself "Ngrams not found: little red ridding hood"

Are you sure the book says "ride with a hood" wouldn't it be "a hood for riding"? An exposed head while riding a horse, especially when  the English weather is  quite intemperate, could lead to colds, sniffles and the like.

@Mari-LouA Google does not mention all actual hits; if they are too few, then there is no plot; so,  "very rare or inexistent" is more precise. // The book does not mention that one, but "walking stick" is in the book's list (which is quite longer), and the pattern is the same: as the stick is an instrument that makes walking easier, more comfortable, similarly the hood is an instrument that makes riding more comfortable; incidentally, you can say as well "stick for walking". I suppose other analyses are acceptable, but I haven't researched this question beyond what can be had from CoGEL.

The analysis: ride with a hood [ride with a hood] is in block quotes as if you were quoting from the CGEL when in actual fact you've added that interpretation yourself. The hood does not make riding a horse any easier whereas a stick can make it easier to walk for someone who is slightly or severely impaired. As for red ridding hood if there are four or even  three examples within Google books that's quite an easy thing to find..Can you find and post the link to one example of usage?

@Mari-LouA   Here is an occurrence. "Riding" goes beyond the mere ability to remain on a horse's back, it means braving the weather, and the hood is used against the cold; it's not really a matter of opinion to accept that a polar jacket makes it easier to withstand sub-zero temperatures. Such like jackets are tools of the trade in cold-storage work. https://www.flexitog.com/shop/category/area-of-work-cold-storage-clothing-16

That example is not spelled ridding though, is it? And even when youtube videos have the title ridding , when the actual video plays, the conventional spelling, and meaning of "riding"  is used: https://youtu.be/DPFhTW7NbUI?si=-ngIk0oyYFMypWfX&t=8 The double d is in the noun phrase is always due to a typo and carelessness.

Note the instances where riding cloak  appeared in 19th century books -a strong contender as a synonym–it may or may not have had a hood, (in most cases I believe it did) and it referred to a type of coat without sleeves for people who rode on horses.

@Mari-LouA True, errors, but they are enough to insinuate into the casual reader's head that there could be a two-d variant. // The following research in Google Books is much more representative of the importance of this synonym; it was then much more frequent, which explains that it is today more important in discussions that concern the past (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riding+cloak%2Criding+hood&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

You mean the casual non-native speaker's  head when they don't know the difference between the verbs rid and ride. Why are you insisting that this misspelling has relevance. It does not. (EDIT You've admitted it is probably a misspelling.) yay

@Mari-LouA  I mean any reader, since it is well know that spelling is something rather erratic that is sometimes not at all predictable from common notions, although I must admit, in this case two d's is very surprising to me. Oh no, I am not insisting that it has relevance; I am merely warning that it should not be spelled that way; there are three cases of such spelling at least, the OP's, the video I found and your video, and this is reason enough for noticing it; this should be considered as a mere remark, no big deal.
